# How do you manually pass generic parameter to a method

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

I have the method:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> stream(JSONArray array) {
    return IntStream.range(0, array.length()).mapToObj(i -> {
        try {
            return (T) array.get(i);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

When I call it like this: `stream(array).map((JSONObject object) -> { /* ... */ })`, I get the error

> Cannot infer functional interface type

And, `stream<JSONObject>(array).map(object -> { /* ... */ })` doesn't work.

`stream(array).map(object -> { /* ... */ })` works, but `object` is simply an `Object`

Comment: If you want help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done.

Comment: You need to use `mapToObj` to get stream of objects. Using map still returns `IntStream`.

Comment: Then you can delete the whole line: you're never doing anything with the stream anyway.

Comment: @Andronicus I am using `mapToObj`...

Comment: @Tobiq not in the second one

Comment: @Andronicus `stream` returns a `Stream`... not an `IntStream`

Answer (score 3):

> And, `stream<JSONObject>(array).map(object -> { /* ... */ })` doesn't work.

That's because you've put the type witness in the wrong place. Try:

```
TheContainingClass.<JSONObject>stream(array).map(object -> { /* ... */ })
```

But your code is not type safe: the cast to `T` is unchecked. You should simply return a `Stream<JSONObject>`, and let the caller handle the casting to other types.

Comment: I'm not actually going to use this function, I'm playing around with generics to better under stand their uses. For one, I'm inserting nulls into the stream on errors

Comment: @Tobiq then you should try to understand why such a usage of generics is so dangerous.